# Where is the engine temperature sensor located on a Mazda 323?

Tags: mazda, coolant, o2-sensor, temperature, astina-323

2003 Mazda 323 Astina, 1.8l, I am trying to figure where the engine temperature sensor is located in the car.

How can I tell if it's faulty? I am only guessing it is because the car overheats, the coolant boils when I drive and radiator fan won't turn on but the A/C fan works.

Answer (score 1):

I am only answering where the sensor is located.This video explains the whole procedure is nicely. Including the location and how to replace it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2vXZbFjlxI